# Remove Custom Divs from AMP pages

Tags: php, functions, videos

I am using Automattic's plugin to implement AMP on my website. Currently, to make my videos responsive, I wrap YouTube videos around a custom div. So, a YouTube video on my website looks like this:-

```
<div class="yt">
<iframe>....YT video code...</iframe>
</div>
```

The problem is the `<div class="yt">` and the closing `</div>` both appear on the AMP pages too. How can I remove them? Already tried asking on the official support. No replies yet.

Comment: How are you adding them? With code? Or just in the editor?

Comment: If you are asking about the custom div, I add them via the editor. So, when I have to add a video, I go to the HTML Editor for the post and add the video embed code within the custom yt div

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Thomas' answer to my question at StackOverflow - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53158606/remove-div-with-a-class-without-removing-content

Here's how you can do it on Wordpress for AMP. In your theme's `functions.php` add the following:-

```
add_action( 'pre_amp_render_post', 'amp_vid_rmv' );
   function amp_vid_rmv() {
add_filter( 'the_content', 'amp_vid_div_rmv' );
} 
function amp_vid_div_rmv($content) {
   $content = preg_replace('#<div class="yt">([\s\S]*?)</div>#', '$1', $content);
   return $content;
}
```

Please feel free to improve on this.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you want to delete not the html code but shortcode. Then use something like that:

```
add_action( 'pre_amp_render_post', 'amp_vid_rmv' );
   function amp_vid_rmv() {
add_filter( 'the_content', 'amp_vid_div_rmv' );
} 
function amp_vid_div_rmv($content) {
  $content = preg_replace('#\[shortcode_name_here\]<br \/>#', '$1', $content);
   ?> <div>in func 9 </div> <?php 
   return $content;
}
```